# gnuplot: How to plot each line of a data file as Y and incremental X

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file containing 30 columns and N rows. Each rows correspond to 30 values of function f(x) for x={1,...,30}. The data file has following pattern:

```
#<index> f(1) f(2) ... f(30)
1 7.221 5.302 ... -1.031
2 4.527 3.193 ... 0.410
...
N 6.386 1.321 ... -0.386
```

gnuplot interprets first column as X and the second one as Y. But, what I want is to plot each line in a separated output file without transposing this data file. For example, for the first line, the desired output would be what gnuplot gets with this input file:

```
# X Y
1 7.221
2 5.302
...
30 -1.031
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATED** based on @Christoph's comment:

```
plot for [i=2:30] 'data.dat' using (i-1):(column(i)) with linespoint
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not which I'm looking for. The output of this would be these points (1,y1), (1,y2), ... (1,y30) for the first line of 'data.dat'. The desired answer is (1,y1), (2,y2), ..., (30,y30).

Comment: It doesn't work properly. It plots not row by row, but column by column. The answer below is correct.

Answer (score 10):

I found a solution:

```
plot "data.dat" matrix every 1::1 with linespoint
```

- `matix` indicates data file type by which the input file interpreted as matrix.
- `every 1::1` skip the first column

Comment: Is there a way to color each line differently?

Comment: @JakubPietkun Yes, [there is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20983399). It seems, `plot "data.dat" matrix using 1:3:2 every 1::1 with linespoints palette` will do the trick.