# Gnuplot: Plotting one series per line of input values

Tags: python, matplotlib, gnuplot

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
fft_0,fft_1,fft_2,fft_3,fft_4,fft_5,fft_6,fft_7,fft_8,fft_9,fft_10,fft_11,fft_12,fft_13,fft_14,fft_15,fft_16,fft_17,fft_18,fft_19,fft_20,fft_21,fft_22,fft_23,fft_24,fft_25,fft_26,fft_27,fft_28,fft_29,fft_30,fft_31,fft_32,fft_33,fft_34,fft_35,fft_36,fft_37,fft_38,fft_39,fft_40,fft_41,fft_42,fft_43,fft_44,fft_45,fft_46,fft_47,fft_48,fft_49,fft_50,fft_51,fft_52,fft_53,fft_54,fft_55,fft_56,fft_57,fft_58,fft_59,fft_60,fft_61,fft_62,fft_63,fft_64,fft_65,fft_66,fft_67,fft_68,fft_69,fft_70,fft_71,fft_72,fft_73,fft_74,fft_75,fft_76,fft_77,fft_78,fft_79,fft_80,fft_81,fft_82,fft_83,fft_84,fft_85,fft_86,fft_87,fft_88,fft_89,fft_90,fft_91,fft_92,fft_93,fft_94,fft_95,fft_96,fft_97,fft_98,fft_99,fft_100,fft_101,fft_102,fft_103,fft_104,fft_105,fft_106,fft_107,fft_108,fft_109,fft_110,fft_111,fft_112,fft_113,fft_114,fft_115,fft_116,fft_117,fft_118,fft_119,fft_120,fft_121,fft_122,fft_123,fft_124,fft_125,fft_126,fft_127,fft_128,fft_129,fft_130,fft_131,fft_132,fft_133,fft_134,fft_135,fft_136,fft_137,fft_138,fft_139,fft_140,fft_141,fft_142,fft_143,fft_144,fft_145,fft_146,fft_147,fft_148,fft_149,fft_150,fft_151,fft_152,fft_153,fft_154,fft_155,fft_156,fft_157,fft_158,fft_159,fft_160,fft_161,fft_162,fft_163,fft_164,fft_165,fft_166,fft_167,fft_168,fft_169,fft_170,fft_171,fft_172,fft_173,fft_174,fft_175,fft_176,fft_177,fft_178,fft_179,fft_180,fft_181,fft_182,fft_183,fft_184,fft_185,fft_186,fft_187,fft_188,fft_189,fft_190,fft_191,fft_192,fft_193,fft_194,fft_195,fft_196,fft_197,fft_198,fft_199,fft_200,fft_201,fft_202,fft_203,fft_204,fft_205,fft_206,fft_207,fft_208,fft_209,fft_210,fft_211,fft_212,fft_213,fft_214,fft_215,fft_216,fft_217,fft_218,fft_219,fft_220,fft_221,fft_222,fft_223,fft_224,fft_225,fft_226,fft_227,fft_228,fft_229,fft_230,fft_231,fft_232,fft_233,fft_234,fft_235,fft_236,fft_237,fft_238,fft_239,fft_240,fft_241,fft_242,fft_243,fft_244,fft_245,fft_246,fft_247,fft_248,fft_249,fft_250,fft_251,fft_252,fft_253,fft_254,fft_255
0.0,31.751653360516546,6.275520840013165,14.595752130320351,3.7868790683610323,23.453145120657318,17.968676508902426,13.077879510660095,5.524149879619814,9.159839191815607,3.4879570496415435,5.789890348672875,6.37158005487321,3.53593114100446,9.005729135469483,11.511943709884944,4.877113072123605,3.980766752139159,11.482684912439783,17.220737110365697,27.088212459502966,110.93476064590726,59.78887389689556,32.51075628874421,24.591418574709603,4.640853279203423,7.448545851889065,9.188366734225628,11.366826382304204,10.077018109797907,3.1841494684815577,5.190248731077729,3.4161263016208325,2.2026391207219995,14.97641334282317,5.673077411085896,12.884780698455764,6.998674823994672,7.342744118836382,3.949308507257039,4.395757811042787,16.103476980952966,28.2719870806011,10.88302198678709,2.685111390491833,10.686339936971915,6.408929713964431,12.069758412421345,15.72375095954655,4.119204604927627,14.874704697329062,11.498505785311869,11.117260027598117,9.494678844281257,5.266405910530414,10.915082550855102,8.417975130307454,18.801404884876543,29.51008177200432,10.843737620239258,20.365544144100863,49.61885082721084,24.743136974252824,95.12429979320565,216.99226248669268,49.341356893894115,18.766444144153137,51.565370474695136,43.7242611005549,54.48857810233984,43.66891218332103,26.853261639029913,6.866934892914652,11.299141562323118,5.318490604101198,31.524180684221047,21.059671101201328,11.17069564618422,17.446945303923478,15.79632859533589,25.8754797065767,25.202369290835293,40.374088558894044,26.000283711509223,55.62708932638661,66.77073066677998,71.71203146112138,48.980985792557924,14.286410652210266,4.601609981437789,15.070118260346232,23.802325341146616,8.327118721719636,11.442341360890286,22.05004217818876,11.104160787103668,12.484928716546818,9.739491305620902,5.5297569624177,7.37163250954064,35.75106868880271,7.399083813594336,26.329051989363144,16.913714138751928,22.74781071883487,20.59299921308038,41.09358072023589,81.47189388863296,61.740342954926696,12.309218911196457,10.244104070553457,4.305193519431507,4.316878112694274,15.939544124902632,12.56060454938032,6.747750800215833,10.325389983324909,14.998130859829269,28.18890104826635,11.0605430438416,8.185204031195694,26.87475337528722,12.662790798826446,41.035417238947375,65.0858268884065,65.54994660181138,21.677593542254662,149.35573051267886,212.42969462503808,74.30926892134302,24.507354570739256,40.76411049649439,35.10651624387605,36.09565222913914,23.539710351057625,25.542632631949893,4.102760694986416,11.980098370080432,13.609502549213738,21.93156128168799,10.081283648530139,15.769674404840714,5.192044221522882,11.771446279635393,12.094956753577113,9.917024863836527,1.2572695424313944,3.722053458526404,8.795658724551126,21.56071410293817,28.922799068534882,13.483122896667437,10.395965791400695,23.505506841117732,8.485560877844723,2.356254230310154,28.165902806102135,12.980298399346841,16.336712296798527,6.730154151533989,16.677864587364514,3.3409877465665216,7.077281578595023,6.446743875035899,19.33833179858605,11.2040774924139,23.43426023135171,21.06169641831372,8.485140511390588,9.068503134834177,3.670077295125947,19.14430606857007,32.42559040891663,28.48925355507031,7.279904785720349,25.259393926407167,20.742537308065206,24.09984129072362,11.414295313454046,3.6413514677095136,41.19050815699398,9.206157892358178,19.755370447153105,36.994783243438796,32.80074469851852,35.87411321258091,11.503107316858005,74.10255021280251,67.24504666591955,104.16768866937738,95.33294914217088,151.9884214593015,136.32292370844223,216.3859464252064,123.41220158493012,59.26669418804178,80.98912876710403,146.95475095348888,46.520877172048024,40.11129083574055,31.4062153719097,51.2525380944314,19.618477161063097,24.64912362290385,39.665889309349865,4.5420695812167695,12.352393331711527,12.913093028159468,5.7475173407962785,32.16753002725559,1.7358492153434433,8.723950884616885,12.467271027329899,14.083802770107315,17.92250369303905,7.86710602026345,7.794809991411701,13.58518272133987,6.524921604389587,15.979388080578659,16.559110564691427,20.67916970007909,18.224245061592946,7.096787929904062,8.373793561958955,6.55812817381509,13.905987460060079,20.595153639426073,8.807333502576107,13.82796348336836,2.18887726814401,6.318371489436107,2.993337999476443,18.749653399598177,6.345591182705673,9.761309360285061,30.96989586919761,8.11119534172852,10.866890070470923,11.517755176146323,27.4609347160214,16.135144173727756,10.6448246437425,4.154792885980834,17.62396431228251,9.509942088880527,15.555429074090473,15.031228264687387,0.9801466560635561,0.7645844300931341,14.154728612808947,12.552555345029779,32.44796170517449,19.530604457901777,11.95976683879656,46.42256522056603
0.0,19.16432992306051,19.616997783340636,24.44119947886979,4.201389789467854,21.74285992321492,21.832776487663676,5.487401249578947,11.746651370331632,1.9601369533755433,5.622561176369094,4.96631977374031,10.097588355385781,5.08483320481312,9.445414620036079,14.222808225039186,2.696213466317052,7.638899760644791,15.041153329998348,10.391749304040763,32.3476575096254,108.99204640400545,63.57497610505674,22.696101813324205,7.872359102700095,21.52130460513689,10.111810799980553,12.724059804396923,19.009158214375578,12.65449693937476,9.132000916109536,6.326763343031359,4.879855924465264,3.871345327977384,10.924451311265537,7.589696386926958,8.18649996093532,11.551503954959513,11.064148190492709,6.176531003718973,15.62762103722472,11.29474719219796,15.477100373471712,34.31169456951676,4.869630599520906,15.140471298507281,8.259616875565543,7.215380685669043,10.46794882830988,19.43560849652611,4.529173954916338,4.35512822937366,2.895187451236368,12.790221568530207,15.09029777868783,17.31295887292244,6.845725037238285,11.696984535700611,29.19412768846885,10.816150558470914,17.795519392349565,18.95627545053494,19.39179148839016,51.25978750420467,258.9220546686427,26.60895810146767,60.12526975188942,57.965437788392094,56.17033578719,61.73076599694442,42.65192391821165,11.56253870818451,25.30486166396842,14.689367444907104,17.68946470063505,12.000531269987114,22.046788191423992,10.461190794614817,15.381278597253058,20.56941785579303,11.378832916602038,17.079026604217585,27.64811379662995,15.945260538344455,17.85973583587812,91.07244530248128,38.79336310420707,9.977752149534174,4.141735910598209,12.882679361205826,7.206277012438345,10.771526867887964,5.877615826490578,12.242065277916515,13.334594521312354,4.29007685290975,7.68709934271143,18.61924420361514,8.74553477917526,8.73628302646769,20.257192090857302,28.872335112983553,4.536051852152141,30.617387864205337,17.858689013107693,41.73630055399866,58.39281594824643,87.24012438534487,31.066544056426327,41.13149447740131,32.42269508871998,26.269987698517536,11.740763622173773,11.004766324349793,18.09863936075447,9.819248943124844,12.893499378743552,10.563553823125307,39.29361373727987,12.346894479852338,8.459770692508902,57.310236078713004,33.1311985608261,28.907897941787073,70.32655132146188,84.24779353195314,61.25485848237276,84.84845471667461,288.2138613792481,109.16667530743895,77.57183940606394,87.3425139617006,68.57701371566155,45.68772118776169,50.0797905239745,33.09749205216209,18.007490834401867,16.334260550527407,31.433003074249346,9.246945751725423,7.074363738698788,4.307268210922044,19.74271610979451,12.91162042059288,21.84937055988338,32.36398718338645,7.281588590668135,10.08373606540601,24.552336456417798,14.7860174786099,21.65070646215015,7.715805417675984,10.173892601354071,10.838760273837256,29.862805175973264,20.040881398274966,26.198025016148872,7.413741554718165,17.48934776894029,6.937450524150569,12.17991859460801,11.285099309978527,16.819830852613755,8.77192614757165,12.64143434466125,25.385516815011027,7.3675506195003875,12.129509801209169,28.94513170225861,20.395460170229377,22.488513131279987,21.01810252560465,35.136025982361815,10.139560341414699,3.555043053681657,31.343112942532223,14.592550641227064,17.64468740002523,26.880409076658076,22.11422795022885,27.4977856180402,30.104920205536807,39.53169334361884,11.71294285354865,23.425805677846594,67.79219601206428,42.27107919700437,64.88620076244453,117.15891789296428,99.78292099303975,48.71538731259637,90.15956877488314,95.77784729934608,101.95350156422501,96.21863000138868,142.43852409191666,151.1858655495999,120.64765073899484,79.83194264924788,65.59195836122893,31.013619590967267,23.420785189214566,28.712244731781265,24.5375312236021,37.231275049400224,22.30698063637999,3.466152702405225,21.930586433683153,12.983286870554023,33.3275146767313,16.019629125908292,13.374161083992483,14.140770556831407,22.17215831856053,11.313270491326389,15.68024673516814,12.986483554144087,23.331903515521233,3.864860667678062,13.76293655930224,29.7546331148781,10.197145120256085,9.949295198338554,23.03483024580453,7.954340759704595,5.206921160805673,12.442782717659927,15.289085530882318,5.497348053429443,6.255156597717796,8.342835500469203,14.66372085309629,16.322270250668957,8.194736256097809,24.397351809392624,17.884522130787275,7.68573327606993,8.180457570504249,33.303256527001146,5.769925562021384,15.466629545524382,12.651255525791012,15.995160619641469,12.922309957994937,6.556673050829525,6.941908198528731,4.617550389093913,27.335731696306702,5.814856112558841,18.49864018853029,13.96291681057734,35.903064134866256,38.73619761839379,32.56594885594187,54.105909842976,30.470991913000084
[...]
```

I want to be able to plot a new series per line (legend not necessary). The x-values should just start at 0 and increment from there, the y-values are given by the numbers in the file. The result should be something like this:

[image]

This was made in Excel, and if it weren't so labourous, this would be fine.

Note that answers using python/matplotlib are also welcomed.

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:** This is as far as I've come, based on the answer provided in [gnuplot: How to plot each line of a data file as Y and incremental X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646446/gnuplot-how-to-plot-each-line-of-a-data-file-as-y-and-incremental-x) and other places. So far, there's for some reason no output file written, although it's definitely doing *something* (because the last command takes a few seconds to finish).

```
set term png
set output "fft.png"
set datafile sep ','
plot for [i=1:255] 'fft.csv' using (i):(column(i)) with lines
```

**EDIT 2:** I now have this, which is closer, but still not what I want. Each line in the input file should be a series. It seems now each column is a series.

```
set term png
set output "fft.png"
set datafile sep ','
unset key
plot for [i=1:255] 'fft.csv' using (i):(column(i)) with lines
```

[image: fft2]

Comment: Not an expert in `matplotlib`, but if Python is okay, it should be easy to transform the data to a format that results in the desired output. What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. 
While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, 
they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. 
A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, 
example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). 
The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: give a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/): it uses matplotlib for plotting and might just give you what you need

Comment: Sorry, I forgot my etiquette. How embarrassing. I'll edit the post with what I've tried already.

Comment: I've updated my post with what I have already, in gnuplot. Sorry for not providing it before. :) I've tried with matplotlib as well, but haven't figured it out yet (and can't locate the code currently, did this originally before christmas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, I think I solved it (using the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8716495/666259 and the answer from Christoph):

```
set terminal png size 1920,1080
set datafile sep ","
unset key
set xtics 0,5,255
set title "mytitle"
set autoscale cbfix
plot "fft.csv" matrix using 1:3:2 with lines palette
```

This gives me something like this:

[image: fft plot]

Answer (score 1):

In order to have every line with a different color, use either `palette` or `linecolor variable`:

```
set datafile separator ','
set autoscale cbfix
plot 'file.csv' matrix every :::1 using 1:3:2 with lines palette
```

This uses the row number to color the lines based on the current palette. This is very useful if you have many lines to draw. `set autoscale cbfix` prevents the color range to be extended to the next major tics.

For only a few lines, you could also use

```
plot 'file.csv' matrix every :::1 using 1:3:2 linecolor variable with lines
```

This uses the row number as index for the `linetype`.

Comment: And it looks pretty! :D Thanks! I haven't been able to figure out why you changed "0::1" to ":::1" and added "using 1:3:2"?

Comment: (And apart from being pretty, it's actually pretty useful to have the lines in colour.)

Comment: Sorry for spamming, but... I removed the "every :::1" entirely, which means the whole file is plotted, it seems. That's fine. (I don't have a header in the csv anymore, that might be it.) I haven't been able to figure out the "using 1:3:2", though. No graph is produced without it, but why are we using these columns, specifically? Documentation on "using" and "palette" still leaves me a bit baffled.

Comment: Usually, with a data file that has three columns, the `using 1:3:2` means, that the first column is used as x-value, the third column is used as y-value and the second column is the line color. With the `matrix` option, the column number is available as first column, the row number as second column and the actual matrix value as third column.