# GNUPLOT Plot many series as lines next to each other

Tags: graph, plot, gnuplot

I am not sure I can accomplish what I am trying to do with gnuplot.

I am not sure whether it would be better to plot my data as a colored surface plot or in the following way:

Firstly, here is an explanation of my data format.

The first column contains time values. The time typically does something like `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...`. For each time, the row next to the time value contains the data I would like to plot. (This is the y-data on a 2D plot, the x-data is the x index (row index) of the data minus 1 for the first column which contains the time index.

I have many (~ 1000) time values.

So it looks something like this:

Sorry for awful color choice.

[image: Example data]

Essentially I would like to plot a line graph for each time value, and put these 2d plots side by side in a 3d plot.

Can I even do this with gnuplot?

I hope the question is clear, if not I can try and add more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
plot 'data.txt' matrix using ($1-1):3:2 every 1::1 with linespoints palette
```

- your *Excel* data are copied to `data.txt`
- `matrix` mode plots lines series (it's that you want)
- the first and the second parameter in `using` when plotting `matrix` are mode specifiers: `1:3` is *["plot rows of matrix"](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node333.html)*.

Citing [@Cristoph's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20991033),

> "With the matrix option, the column number is available as first
>   column, the row number as second column and the actual matrix value as
>   third column."

- `($1)` would be equal to `1` here, but `($1 - 1)` means *"subtract unity from a column number"* - this way *x* would start from *0* for each row.
- `every 1::1` - do not include the first column with time values into plot.
- at last `using ..:..:2` allows you to set different colors (equal to row number) for the `palette` option.

[The answer is based on similar question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20991033)