# Plot csv file with multiple rows using gnuplot

Tags: csv, gnuplot

I have a csv file which contains 500 rows and 100 columns.

I want to plot the data in the way that:

1. Each row represent a curve on the graph. Every column represents a
   value on the curve (100 values).
2. 500 such curves on the graph.

The code:

```
set xrange [0:100]
set yrange [0:20]
set term png
set output 'output.png'
set datafile separator ','
plot 'myplot.csv'
```

But this does not seem to work.
How can I configue gnuplot to achieve that?

Edit:

The data is in this format (Shortened):

```
7.898632397,7.834565295,8.114238484,7.636553599,7.759415909,7.829112422
7.898632397,8.379427648,8.418542273,7.921914453,7.558814684,7.237529826
7.898632397,7.862492565,8.132579657,8.419279034,8.350564183,8.578430051
7.898632397,7.613394134,7.213820144,7.42985323,7.74212712,7.144952258
7.898632397,7.736819889,8.14247944,8.025533212,8.256498438,8.133741173
7.898632397,7.906868959,8.032605101,8.308540463,8.238641673,8.143985756
```

Comment: Could you give us the error or something?  It's impossible to help troubleshoot without any diagnostic data.

Comment: There is no error. I got an empty output file.

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646446/gnuplot-how-to-plot-each-line-of-a-data-file-as-y-and-incremental-x can help

Comment: Can you easily invert the data so each row has a value on the curve and each column is a curve?

Answer (score 0):

```
set datafile separator comma
plot for [row=0:*] 'myplot.csv' matrix every :::row::row with lines
```

However I suspect that with 500 lines the plot will be too crowded to interpret.